# Store values from mutually exclusive group

Tags: python, argparse

After declaring a mutually exclusive group, how are these value accessed. If the user specifies --predict, only 4 values should be allowed and once they are attached, how are they accessed? Here is my code that is not allowing me to access the list of attached numbers:

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Video game preferences: train or predict mode.')
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    group.add_argument('--train', action='store', help='')
    group.add_argument('--predict', nargs=4, type=float, action='store', help=''represented by 1s)')
    arg = parser.parse_args()
    print(arg)
```

And here is how I am calling the program from cmd:

main.py --predict 1 8 7 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`add_mutually_exclusive_group` does not change the syntax for how the arguments are accessed, it only adds additional checks at runtime to raise errors if multiple exclusive args are provided.  You access the value like you do for any other arg, e.g. `arg.train` or `arg.predict` in this example.

Comment: C:\Users\hanna\PycharmProjects\knn_videogame_preference>main.py --predict 1 8 7 6
usage: main.py [-h] (--train TRAIN | --predict PREDICT PREDICT PREDICT PREDICT)
main.py: error: one of the arguments --train --predict is required

Comment: The above comment is my input in cmd and the error I am receiving when I try to print(arg.predict)

Comment: Hmm, that's strange, it's as if it is completely ignoring the `--predict` arg that you are passing in.  Does it work if you use `--train` instead?

Comment: I actually figured out the issue. I added python to the beginning of my cmd command and the problem was solved. Thank you for your help.